# Can you make steam not take dumps when Dota 2 crashes?

Tags: steam, dota-2

Everytime Dota 2 crashes steam makes memory dumps and they're placed in the *C:\Program Files\Steam\dumps*.

Now my problem is that my HDD space is pretty low now, and each "dump" file is a bit over 1 GB. And i really don't have any use for them either, i don't plan on reporting the crashes because I'm pretty sure it wont help me, and it would take too long to upload that anyway (with my upload speed at least).

Is there a way to make steam not make those dump files at every Dota 2 crash?

Comment: You may be able to revoke the corresponding rights from the steam and/or Dota apps to write files to that folder by changing its access policy to read-only. Though it may cause error messages, so try at your own risk.

Comment: Looks like your problem just got solved,check edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of **May 3rd, 2013** (when main DotA 2 client gets patched) DotA 2 crashes **won't create** such large .dmp files.

[Quote](http://dev.dota2.com/showthread.php?t=85087) from the official DotA 2 test client patch notes:

- Update 2 - "Dota 2 will no longer generate full crash dumps"

---

If the problem persists you can try using **CCleaner** program, it can be set to automatically delete those files.

Also you could use [junctions](http://www.rohand.com/2009/how-to-create-a-junction-in-windows-7/) to automatically redirect those files on another disk partition or send them to desktop for easier cleanup.

Answer (score 5):

For what it's worth, it will only be performing a full dump during the beta phase. After that, they will switch to regular minidumps, which are much much smaller... http://dev.dota2.com/showthread.php?t=1533&p=4910&viewfull=1#post4910

Obviously, that could be going on for a long period to come though. In the meantime, you can create scheduled task to regularly clear out that folder... http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/234715-how-schedule-folder-content-deleting-task.html#post1962430

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to stop that since that is a hard coded function in Dota 2. Those minidumps are generated by the program itself.

You should report it though if you get that many crashes...

Comment: I only get around 1 crash per day (after playing for hours and hours). Sometimes 2 but not more then that. They do add up after a while though.